# JQuery Mobile get JSON from url

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-mobile

UPDATED

I'm trying to incorporate some JSON data into a JQuery Mobile page. Using the following example code, I can get this to work, however when I use my own url the code fails to produce any content on screen.

Here is the starter -working- code:

```
    var li = "";
$.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=cat&tagmode=any&format=json&jsoncallback=?",
    function(data){
      $.each(data.items, function(i,item){
        li += '<li><a href="#" id="' + i + '" class="info-go">' + item.author + '</a></li>';
          $("#prof-list").append(li);
      });
    });
```

However, when I adapt the code to incorporate my own url JSON feed no content is produced.

```
    //set up string for adding <li/>
var li = "";
$.getJSON("http://aviationapp.codeclinic.de/showAvBuyerResults.aspx?source=avbuyer&resultSet=resultsbymodel&manufacturer=piper&model=arrow&callback=cheese",
    function(data){
      $.each(data, function(i,item){
        li += '<li><a href="#" id="' + i + '" class="info-go">' + manufacturer + '</a></li>';
          $("#prof-list").append(li);
      });
    });
```

Ive even gone so far as to format the JSON from my url to be similar to that of the Flickr url/JSON used in the example, but i still get no visible results.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong / why its not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ASP.NET code isn't using the `jsoncallback` query string parameter to determine the function name for the JSON-P response.

It is also claiming that the response is `text/html` instead of `application/javascript`

Comment: Any pointers on what needs to be done with the jsoncallback query?

Comment: You use it as the name of the function you call in your JSON-P.

Comment: Sorry Quentin, Im not sure what you mean.

Comment: Do you know what JSON-P is?

Comment: I've seen it referenced but not found anything actually explains it.

Comment: Since you are attempting to use it, that's something of a problem. The Wikipedia article is good: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Comment: Indeed. Ill go take a look at that link. Thanks.

Comment: Hey Quentin, Ive got my JSON being pushed out with the correct header now, but I still dont get this jsoncallback query bit. Sorry for not getting it. Ive tried to get my head around it but it simply isnt going well.

Comment: Look at the wikipedia article. `functionCall` is what is specified by `jsoncallback`

Comment: Quentin, I think I've worked it out the JSONP bit now but its still not displaying anything. So clearly Ive still not got something(s) right. If you could take a look again, now that Ive updated stuff, I'd seriously appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: You've replaced the `?`, in the JS string for the URL, with the word `cheese`. jQuery doesn't know that it needs to generate a callback function or where to specify the name of that function the URL.

Comment: Ok well from what I understood you take the value of callback and make that the name of the function. However, from your response it's evident that, that is no the correct thing to do. Ok. I think Ill need to look at doing something different altogether. Thanks for the help and tips. Its been greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's what the server needs to do. The client needs to determine what the callback function is called and then stick that name in the URL so the server can do it. jQuery will do that by replacing the `?` in the URL with the name of the callback function it is generating.

Comment: Ok. Well I'm not sure what just happened but I changed the response header / content type to: 'application/x-javascript' rather than 'application/x-javascript' and now it works. Any idea what the significance is?